# How to data-bind "mousedown" instead of "click" on an HTML button?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following button that is currently using `data-bind="click: ..."` and I was wondering if it is at all possible to use "mousedown" instead of "click".

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="button button--sm" data-bind="click: setVersion9, css: { 'button--primary': isVersion9Selected()  }">Code Version 9</span>
```

Currently when clicking the UI button, if the press and release of the mouse button happens REALLY quickly, it causes problems with switching between text boxes (ie: it copies the text from one box over to the next one). I was hoping that using "mousedown" would resolve this issue so that I wouldn't have to worry about anyone clicking the button too fast.

Comment: mouseDown is an event that you can attach to via:  `$(item).on("mouseDown", myfunction);`

Comment: @Fallenreaper -- no capital 'D' in there ... should be `.on( "mousedown", handler )`

Comment: so I can't just do `data-bind= "mousedown: setVersion9, ...`, can I?

Comment: `data-bind="click: setVersion9` ... this is using knockout.js?

Comment: See this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Comment: thanks for that reference. that is very helpful and I am bookmarking that for future use!

Comment: @AtlasBowler also for future reference, `data-bind` is a knockoutjs-specific thing. It's not an HTML thing and it's not a jquery thing. Tagging your question appropriately will help people answer you faster & better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `event` binding for any events that don't have a first-class-citizen binding [as described here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html).

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="button button--sm" 
    data-bind="event: { mousedown: setVersion9 }, css: { 'button--primary': isVersion9Selected()  }">Code Version 9</span>
```